# How to explain the Moon halo phenomenon?

Tags: astronomy, moon

Today, here in Brazil, I have observed (and is still observing) an interesting phenomenon.

The Moon is near to a big star in the sky, but this is normal. The interesting part is what's around them.

A huge circle in which the moon and the star is inside. Why does this circle appear? What is it?

(This isn't a cloud. It looks like more something like a light reflection of a lamp.)

Unfortunately, I hadn't a good camera to catch this. I would appreciate having an image posted for this.

Comment: Not so normal, check some ephemerides table, I believe that the star was to be Jupiter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be describing a moon aura.

[image: Moon Aura]

It's caused by **diffraction** on tiny ice crystals in the atmosphere: When the moonlight hits the ice, you get **interference effects** that depend on the angle of the incident light. The idea is similar to powder diffraction in crystallography.

Comment: Yes. It's was I'm looking for.

Comment: Thx about the explanation!

Comment: to expand a little, the crystals are flat but sit in the same orientation and diffract the light through 23 degrees (I think!)

Comment: Also known as "lunar halo" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_%28optical_phenomenon%29#Circular_halo .